# Unable to preview Composables with Koin injection [Android]

Tags: android, dependency-injection, android-jetpack-compose, preview, koin

I am trying to preview a Composable that uses koin dependencies. Per the documentation [here](https://insert-koin.io/docs/reference/koin-compose/compose/#compose-preview-with-koin) you should be able to start a mini KoinApplication in the Preview function to pass the dependency to the preview.

But I still get the following error:

```
Render problem
java.lang.IllegalStateException: KoinApplication has not been started
    at org.koin.core.context.GlobalContext.get(GlobalContext.kt:36)
    at org.koin.core.component.KoinComponent$DefaultImpls.getKoin(KoinComponent.kt:33)
    at com.xyz.utility.MyHelper.getKoin(MyHelper.kt:38)
    at com.xyz.utility.MyHelper$special$$inlined$inject$default$5.invoke(KoinComponent.kt:68)
    ....
```

Here is my preview function

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun PreferencesPreview() {
        KoinApplication(application = {
            // your preview config here
            modules(
                databaseModule,
                networkModule,
                //etc...
            )
        }) {
            // Compose to preview with Koin
            Preferences()
        }
}
```